# How can I get text using jQuery from inside a paragraph after a DIV?

Tags: jquery

Something I am not sure how to do. Using jQuery I want to get the text of the first paragraph that comes after the Div with a class of "ban_hdr".

```
<div class="ban_hdr">
</div>
<p>Which of the following are correct? abc abc</p>
```

Even better if I could get the contents of the first sentence which always ends in a "?"

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = $('.ban_hdr').next('p').text();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/vMcQ5/)

Answer (score 1):

try this `$('div+p').text();` for specifying class 
`alert($('div.ban_hdr + p').text());`

Comment: This works, but it will require the use of Sizzle so @Shef's answer will be much faster.

Comment: @sushil bharwani: [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is the alien's weapon which jQuery has incorporated since version [1.3](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3) to make its selector engine look cool.

Answer (score 0):

To get read text from a paragraph tag inside a div use this

```
$("#ban_hdr").children("p").text();
```

& to write text into a paragraph tag inside a div use this

```
$("#ban_hdr").children("p").text("new text in p tag. Hope this helps :P ");
```